# NGINX include json file at both locations

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx code which I would like to have json files passing through both locations. Having the following code, json files passes only via the second location. What is needed in order to have both locations "enabled" for json. I want to make sure that the first location contains the /new URI (+several other sub-URIs).

```
location /new/ {
proxy_http_version     1.1;
proxy_pass http://new_upstream;
}


location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|json|fs)$ {
proxy_pass http://upstream;
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, what exactly do you mean by "json files passing through both locations"? Can you give examples of request URLs and what each URL should serve?

Comment: first location: <URL>/new/test1/test.json

second location: <URL>/one/use.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [nginx documentation for location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), nginx first matches exact matches (`= /path`), then prefix matches (`/path`), and remembers best match.

Then it proceeds to check for regular expression matches, and uses it if something is found.

If one wants to prevent regular expression matches for a `location`, one needs to use the `^~` specifier in the `location`:

```
location ^~ /new/ {
    proxy_http_version        1.1;
    proxy_pass http://new_upstream;
}

location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|json|fs)$ {
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
}
```

However, this configuration forces all requests with prefix `/new` to be processed by that block. No JPG / JPEG / JSON / FS extensions will be served by the second block for `/new` block.